# Implementing SSL or HTTPS in GWT

Tags: gwt, ssl

I am building an application in GWT.
I need to implement SSL or HTTPS in application as security is the key factor of my appln.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: implement how? used for what? "security" is not some concrete thing you can just drop into a project.

Comment: A bit hard to figure what you want... that? http://c.gwt-examples.com/home/server/app-engine/ssl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL and HTTPS have nothing to do with GWT. You configure SSL on your web server.

Comment: in that way i should be able to force the application to https. is it??

Comment: HTTPS is not related to "application". It's a communication protocol between a browser and a web server.